# Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, nimbus-jose-jwt

Using Spring Boot OAuth Resource Server starter project, Version - 2.4.4.
I'm receiving the below exception, I couldn't find much problem in code as it worked fine in our preprod env
but not working in prod environment 
**Observation so far,** 
I have checked , and want to confirm **if kid received from jwk uri and kid received from token is different , then  Is it possible for this exception ?** Note , kid is same for token and jwk uri in pre-prod env.
**from jwk uri** - 
[image] 
**from jwt header** - 
[image]
Looked into this [code](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/4.2/src-html/com/nimbusds/jwt/proc/DefaultJWTProcessor.html) , for key id checking snippet , line no- 253 .. but i couldn't understand further into it.

```
com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:384) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-8.20.2.jar:8.20.2]
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:330) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-8.20.2.jar:8.20.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:153) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This exception is expected if the `kid` from your token and the `kid` from the  JWKS endpoint do not match.

Double-check your configuration, it's possible you have a client attempting to use a token from a different issuer (may from your pre-prod).

The JWT *should* contain an `iss` field in the body that should help you track down the problem.

Comment: yes i double checked kid is different for token and JWKS endpoint , i need to check with our Admin why is it so then .. thanks for confirmation

Comment: could you comment on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049215/in-nimbus-jose-jwt-what-is-difference-between-lifespan-and-refreshtime

Comment: could you please add some reference docs for reading more about this